# Google search: Scrape results page in PHP for total results

Tags: php

Is it possible to scrape the Google search results page using PHP to pull out the total number of search results found?

If so how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I think this is against the terms of service ;)

Comment: Google offers a search api that can be used via PHP. Never used it but getting the total search results might be possible with it: http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje_snippets

Comment: If you scrape the results directly a few times in a row then Google will probably block your IP.  If you plan on doing this regularly then you will have to go through a proxy or limit the number of connections you make per hour

Comment: **important clarification**: Do you just want the NUMBER of total search results (which is simple - you just want the number itself) or do you want the total search results themselves? The latter is not something Google will let you have with white hat methods, but may be attained through the powers of Scrapebox and the dark side.

Answer (score 7):

try this using [phpsimplehtmlparser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$search_query = 'google';
$url = sprintf('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s', $search_query);
$html = file_get_html($url);
$results = $html->find('#resultStats/b', 2)->innertext;

echo sprintf('Google found %s results for "%s"', $results, $search_query);
```

Answer (score 5):

This PHP class does it: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/3924.html

> "This class can be used to get the
>   total number of results for given
>   Google search query.
>
> It accesses the Google search site to
>   perform a query for given search
>   terms.
>
> The class parses the results page and
>   extract the total number of results
>   that the given search query returned."

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a bunch of proxies depending on the number of requests you plan to send. 
You can send about 500 requests per day and IP/proxy without causing trouble or getting detected.

You should read up at the google-rank-checker.squabbel.com article, it contains a full featured scraper in PHP. Use that scraper, modify it to your requirements and add the code of phpsimplehtmlparser (the other answer) to get the total-hits information for the keywords.

I suggest the use of libCURL for accessing Google itself.
You will have a LOT more options than using a more simple API, you'll not have much fun with file_get_html() or similar php internal functions as Google would block your script very soon.

Something like this:

```
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1);
  $curl_proxy = "$IP:$PORT";
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $curl_proxy);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/2009011913 Firefox/3.0.6");
  $url = sprintf('http://www.google.com/search?q=%s', $keyword);
  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $htmdata = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Now just use regex()/substr()/strstr() to grab the data from $htmldata

Answer (score 1):

I AM using this php script to find out the total results of my name in google's search .

`<?php

$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.google.co.in/search?ix=nh&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Mohit+dabas');

preg_match('/(About )?([\d,]+) result/si', $homepage, $p) ;

echo $p[0];

?>`

the main thing to be noticed is '&q' parameter  in the path defined above

My name contain space  so the browser added '+' to it

So you should check ur query(i.e &q) parameters and if ur query contain some special

character like ., : ,% etc then you should  note how they are treated by the browser and

change the parameters acc. to your need int script.

srry for the poor english