# How to extract total amount of search results in Google results page

Tags: javascript, php, google-search

I am trying to find and extract the "About 16,600,000 results (0.69 seconds)" text from the Google results page. Not the results, just the String text. After extracting, i want to save the result in an Array and to repeat it twice with other keywords. Afterwards, i will loop through the Array to print it in a table. I don't know why, but if i try to find "results" on the page i always tells me it did not find anything. 
Current code:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.google.co.uk/#q=cheese";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($html, "results") !== false) {
  echo "found";
} else {
  echo "not found";
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search: Scrape results page in PHP for total results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560508/google-search-scrape-results-page-in-php-for-total-results)

Comment: To my knowledge there's no "white hat" way of getting ALL of the search results, because Google doesn't allow it, doesn't even sell it as a service, and throttles macros/plugins/automation-browsers, etc which try to crawl through their pages. One "black hat" way of doing it would be to use ScrapeBox or any other solution that is based on rotating IP addresses and other identifiers with a pool of proxies + spoofing to avoid being throttled. Incidentally, I haven't run your code but there are tons of good examples out on how to scrape results with code or apps, but the challenge is throttling.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because https://www.google.co.uk/#q=cheese only returns a html document, which runs some JavaScript code that fetches the search result in a second call.

(You can disable JavaScript in your browser and visit the page to "see" what file_get_contents would see)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this using `file_get_contents` or `curl` as the other answer already pointed out.

You probably want to look at something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. PhantomJS is a WebKit browser and will enable you to get the results you are lookng for.

Comment: I don't think PhantomJS would help with this, because Google will throttle it after a couple of results pages.